# JSON.parse does not work and exits function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Here's my problem

I'm trying to replace this structure :

1. PHP:

   ```
   $mainContent = getContenu($_GET['rq']);
   die($mainContent);
   ```
2. JS:

   ```
   $('#contenu').html(data);
   ```

With this one :

1. PHP:

   ```
   $envoi['mainContent'] = getContenu($_GET['rq']);
   die(json_encode($envoi));
   ```
2. JS:

   ```
   $('#contenu').html(JSON.parse(data).mainContent);
   ```

With the first option, everything works just fine.
What happens is : In my JS file `index.js`, the snippet that I've written above is inside a structure as such :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   (...)
   $('.menu a').click(function(){
      (...)
      $.get('index.php',rq=' + rq, function(data){
         //---->IT'S IN HERE<----//
      });
   });
});
```

The `getContenu()` function just returns the `implode()` version of an html or php file (depending on `rq`).

The second option (using JSON) seems to exit the `$.get` function as soon as it hits `JSON.parse()`. I've tried using the parse function outside of the `$('#contenu').html()` but `var whatevs = JSON.parse(data)` as well as `var whatevs = JSON.parse(data).mainContent` or `(data)['mainContent']` all produce the same result.

If I put an `alert` before the `JSON.parse` function, it gets called, but if I put one after it, it doesn't call it, which has led me to believe that the `JSON.parse` is the problem.

I've tried to replace the `getContenu` function in the PHP part with some random string just to see if it would work, but nothing happens either.

Thanks for reading me,

Chris

P.S. This is a school project so not using JSON is not an option as it is required by the teacher
P.P.S. I'm running it on the latest build of Chrome so browser's not the issue.

Comment: Don;t `die()` with `die($mainContent);`.. Use `var_dump($mainContent) `then `die()`

Comment: @FrayneKonok What's the difference? `var_dump` will output additional content, and that will break response.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Thanks for the input but it's not that part that troubles me, it's the JSON one. That one works fine, and is bound to be replaced with the json_encode anyway. I tried `var_dump(json_encode($envoi));die();` but it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you add a sample value for the variable? or the JSON response.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Can you be more precise ? What variable ?

Comment: can you try `console.log(data)` before you do the parse?

Comment: use `echo` instead of `var_dump` or `die`. Try to pass parameters to your `$.get` function like so: `$.get('index.php',{name: value}, function(data){`

Answer (score 0):

OK so I don't know exactly what happened. For some reason it now works. I've not changed anything (I've browsed my Ctrl + Z and Ctrl + Maj + Z through and through to see what I changed but nothing is different, just some alerts and the `console.log(data)` that @ReijithRKrishnan suggested... But now it works without that line too. I'm speechless... IT is so full of mystery sometimes...

Comment: i can understand ;)